# Best way to implement a weapon/tool swing

Tags: monogame

In some games like Keplerth or Archvale, a weapon basically points towards the mouse and stays around the player sprite. But when you attack the weapon swings. I don't believe this is done with a spritesheet style animation.

This is somewhat easy to achieve in a game engine like GMS 2, Unity or Godot. But there are multiple ways to implement this in a lower level framework like say MonoGame or using OpenGL. For example having the state for a weapon or maybe using a tween function.

What would be the best way to implement this in MonoGame? Is there a tutorial for such an implementation?

I can provide examples of what I mean if required.

Comment: It's very rare in games that there's an objective "best" way to do something, so this form of the question may not be answerable. A better way is to tentatively pick a strategy that seems to make sense to you, and flesh it out into a plan, to see if you spot a problem. If not, continue and build a prototype to test whether it performs adequately or if you hit a problem in practice. If not, congrats, your solution is good enough! If you do hit a problem, edit your question to describe your plan/attempt in detail and identify the specific problem to solve, to focus answers on what you need.

Comment: [See more about the problem with "best" questions here](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/q/636/39518). Requests for off-site tutorials are also not on-topic here. The way to find existing resources elsewhere on the net is to use a search engine. Ask here when you want answers *here* because you already researched what's available in already -published tutorials and identified a gap that needs new material to be written.

Comment: I highly suggest reading this chapter on State from Game Programming Patterns by Robert Nystrom [link](https://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/state.html).